# changing JSpinner value without triggering a change event

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jspinner

In my program I have several JSpinners and other input components that should display some values and react on user's input. The values are related to one another. When value A changes, it changes value B as well. 
The problem is, that when A changes, it changes B and since B changes it changes A again.. and so on.
My question is, how I can listen to the user's input and change all values without triggering a "value changed event" on the other components ?

Here is a simple example with 2 spinners: (SpinnerA will set the value of SpinnerB to two times the value of A)

```
public class SpinnerExample extends javax.swing.JFrame{

    private javax.swing.JSpinner spinnerA;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner spinnerB;

    public SpinnerExample(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());

        // here the interesting part:
        spinnerA = new JSpinner();
        spinnerA.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt){
                System.out.println("Spinner A state changed to value=" + spinnerA.getValue());
               //spinnerB.setValue(spinnerA.getValue());
               spinnerB.setValue(((int) spinnerA.getValue() * 2));
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(spinnerA);

        spinnerB = new JSpinner();
        spinnerB.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt){
                System.out.println("Spinner B state changed to value=" + spinnerB.getValue());
                spinnerA.setValue(spinnerB.getValue());
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(spinnerB);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                new SpinnerExample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In this example there are 2 spinners: **spinnerA** and **spinnerB**. 
Both have their own `ChangeListener` to act when the value changes in any way.
So when clicking on the up arrow of **spinnerA**, the value of **spinnerA** changes to `1` and the *change listener of A* reacts by setting the value of **spinnerB** to `2` (2 times the value of A). - so far so good-
But now the *change listener of B* registers a change again and reacts by setting the value of **spinnerA** to `2`. And again **A** detects a value change and sets **B** to 2xA -> `4` ... and so on

**my dirty solution**
I use a global `boolean doUpdate` variable. `true` by default, it is set to `false` when one of the spinners reacts on a change:

```
public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt){
    if(doUpdate){  // react only when set to true
        doUpdate=false; // temporarily set it to false
        System.out.println("Spinner B state changed to value=" + spinnerB.getValue());
        spinnerA.setValue(spinnerB.getValue()); // the other spinner won't react anymore since doUpdate is false
        doUpdate=true; // when finished, set it to true again.
    }
}
```

For now this seems to "work" but just doesn't feel right. that's way to dirty. How can I even be sure that the other spinner triggers it's change event before `doUpdate` is reset to `true` again?

**does anyone have a cleaner way to stop the change-event-chain?**

Thank you for your time.